# Not found page in NextJs 13.4

Tags: next.js, custom-error-pages

I have 2 questions. But, first, in my `layout.tsx` above `{children}` I also have a custom component `<Navbar />`. I created a 404 page but on that page I also have that navbar. Is there any way to remove that navbar on the not-found.tsx page? And another question, can I add custom classes to the body tag to each page, even 404?

I found a solution somewhere, but, from what I saw from there i need to add `"use client"` in `layout.tsx`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like this is currently an issue for NextJS 13's app directory as seen [here](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/37311#discussioncomment-6993373).

You can place the pages you want with navbar in a separate folder, in this case `(main)` so it won't appear in the route, like so:

```
app
   (main)
     layout.tsx - has navbar
     page.tsx
   layout.tsx - no navbar
   not-found.tsx
```

---

To add custom classes to the body tag, you can place a `useEffect` and get the body like so:

```
export default function Page() {
  useEffect(() => {
    document.body.classList.add("custom-class");
  });

  return <div />;
}
```

And yes you'll have to add in `use client` for this as we're going to have to use `useEffect`